# Get todays from - to timestamps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

So we can get current time stamp with `new Date().getTime()`, but how do I calculate today's from-to timestamps (from midnight to midnight)?

Comment: I would install [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) . Docs [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: Moment is not an option in my case

Comment: There is only 1 midnight per day, do you mean from midnight today, to midnight tommorow?

Comment: Moment is a very common library. Why, may I ask,  is it not an option?

Comment: Read the documentation for the `Date` object. It's just simple math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want from midnight today to midnight tomorrow, without using any 3rd party lib.

You could just do ->

```js
const from = new Date();
const to = new Date(from);
function clearTime(t) {
  t.setMinutes(0);
  t.setSeconds(0);
  t.setMilliseconds(0);
}

from.setHours(0); clearTime(from);
to.setHours(24); clearTime(to);

console.log(from);
console.log(to);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create date from timestamp you can use new Date(timestamp)

```js
let timestamp = 1584532480757;
let date = new Date(timestamp );
document.write(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following. Let me know if you need explanations on the code snippet below.

```js
var now = new Date();
var [year, month, day] = [now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()];
var todayFrom = new Date(year, month, day);
var todayTo = new Date(year, month, day+1);
todayTo = new Date(todayTo.getTime()-1);
console.log(todayFrom);
console.log(todayTo);
console.log(todayFrom.getTime());
console.log(todayTo.getTime());
```